# How can I solve a scoping issue where variable is not maintained outside of kotlin `forEach` loop

Tags: android, kotlin

I am having some scoping issues that I don't know how to solve. In the code below the array `allRecentItems` is not populated after it has been assigned `Items` inside the `forEach` loop.

The idea is to query the Room database for the ID of an `Item` and then use a function `getItemById()` to return the details for the item with that ID by querying a Firestore collection for a document with that ID.

What method can I use to solve this problem? Thanks.

## Approach 1

```
override fun getAllRecentlyTappedItems(callback: (ArrayList<Item>) -> Unit): LiveData<ArrayList<Item>>
{
    val allRecentItems: ArrayList<Item> = arrayListOf()

    launch {

        val recentlyTappedItems: List<EntityRecentItems> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
            itemDatabase.entityRecentlyTappedItem().getAll()
        }

        recentlyTappedItems.forEach { entityRecentItem -> 
            getItemById(entityRecentItem.itemId){ item: Item ->
                allRecentItems.add(item)

                //`item` is present here
                Log.d(
                    this.javaClass.simpleName,
                    "getAllRecentlyTappedItems: {add: ${item.name}}"
                )
            }
        }



        // `allRecentItems` is empty at this point where I need it.
        Log.d(
            this.javaClass.simpleName,
            "getAllRecentlyTappedItems: {final allRecentItems: ${allRecentItems}}"
        )

       mutableLiveDataItemArrayList.postValue(allRecentItems)
    }

    // mutableLiveDataItemArrayList not updated yet.
    return mutableLiveDataItemArrayList
}
```

### getItemById function

```
override fun getItemById(itemId: String, callback: (item: Item) -> Unit)
    {
        firestore.collection(Constants.FirebasePaths.DATABASE_ITEMS)
            .document(itemId)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot ->
                if(documentSnapshot != null)
                {
                    Log.d(this.javaClass.simpleName,
                        "getItemById: {" +
                                "itemName: ${documentSnapshot.data!![Constants.FirebaseDocumentSnapshotKeys.DATABASE_ITEMS_ITEM_NAME].toString()}" +
                                "}")

                    callback(
                        Item(name = documentSnapshot.data!![Constants.FirebaseDocumentSnapshotKeys.DATABASE_ITEMS_ITEM_NAME].toString())
                    )

                }
            }
    }
```

## Approach 2

```
override fun getAllRecentlyTappedItems(callback: (ArrayList<Item>) -> Unit): LiveData<ArrayList<Item>>
{
    launch {

        val listOfRecentItems = async(Dispatchers.IO){
            itemDatabase.entityRecentlyTappedItem().getAll()
        }

        val res = async(Dispatchers.Main) {

            val allRecentItems: ArrayList<Item> = arrayListOf()

            listOfRecentItems.await().forEach { recentItem ->

                Log.d(this.javaClass.simpleName, "getAllRecentlyTappedItems: " +
                "{recentTappedIdFromDatabase: ${recentItem.itemId}}")

                getItemById(recentItem.itemId) {item: Item ->

                    Log.d(this.javaClass.simpleName, "getAllRecentlyTappedItems: " +
                    "{(itemId: ${item.itemId}, itemName: ${item.itemName})}")

                    allRecentItems.add(item)
                }
            }

            // `res` is always empty at this point
            allRecentItems

        }


        // `res.await()` returns an empty array
        Log.d(this.javaClass.simpleName, "getAllRecentlyTappedItems: " +
            "{allRecentItems: ${res.await()}}")

        mutableLiveDataItemArrayList.postValue(res.await())
    }

   return mutableLiveDataItemArrayList
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding exactly what you want to do. Your function has a callback parameter but doesn't use it. It returns a live data that isn't generated internally, which is kind of odd. And nothing in your coroutine even attempts to update the LiveData `mutableLiveDataItemArrayList` that you return. If you're working with LiveData and coroutines, I don't see why this function should have a callback parameter or return a LiveData.

Comment: I would rethink the design here. Either this function should be a suspend function that you call sequentially from a coroutine and returns a List, or it should be a fire-and-forget function that simply updates a LiveData that you've subscribed to elsewhere and not return anything.

Comment: @Tenfour04 the intent of the callback function is to return the value of `allRecentItems` arraylist but since  `allRecentItems` is empty at the point where I need to return it I have not used the callback.

Comment: If your're using a callback, you don't return anything from this function. The callback should be called at the end of your coroutine, *inside* the coroutine. But one of the main points of using coroutines is so you don't have to use callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look into Coroutine.async. Problem is that the method is returning before the launch can execute and complete. You require some asynchronous functionality.

```
val deferred: Deferred<ArrayList<Item>> = GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.IO){
      val recentlyTappedItems: List<EntityRecentItems> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
          itemDatabase.entityRecentlyTappedItem().getAll()
      }
      val recentItems: List<Item> = arrayListOf()
      recentlyTappedItems.forEach { entityRecentItem -> 
          getItemById(entityRecentItem.itemId){ item: Item ->
              recentItems.add(item)
          }
      }
      recentItems
  }
val allRecentItems = deferred.await()
```

This would need to be wrapped in a `suspend` fun I believe.

```
suspend fun getAllRecentItems(): List<Item> {
 // Above snippet
}
```

Your code looks incomplete with regards to `mutableLiveDataItemArrayList` and the methods return type, but I am sure this will help get you to where you need.

Comment: in your snippet `` works as expected but even though logs in the function `getItemById()` show that items are being retrieved successfully from Firestore `item` lambda return variable returns nothing, meaning `recentItems.add(item)` adds nothing to the `recentItems` list